# What should be the mapping for listed tables in Entity Framework (edmx)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have a 3 tables
1. Entity
2. Credentials
3. EntityType

Entity can be Lab, Client or Technician based on EntityType value that can be (1,2,3).
Only Technician i.e. 3 can have credentials.

What should I make changes to get into the required design.

[image]

I am getting following error.

> Error 1   Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   149:Condition member 'Entity.EntityType' with a condition other than
>   'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on
>   Entity.EntityType or remove it from the mapping.  c:\documents and
>   settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\LimsEdm\LimsEdmx\LimsModel.edmx 150 15  LimsEdmx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `EntityType` column for TPH discriminator you cannot map it in the table. It is already used for inheritance mapping and column cannot be mapped twice. Remove `EntityType` property from your `EntityType` entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that mean there should be no table in the database for EntityType and instead should have Check constraint for (1,2,3). What if I want to keep EntityType dynamic. Should there be another entity i.e. OtherUsers which no constraint on value ?

Comment: You need table for `EntityType` and you need that column but you cannot have the column mapped to a property. You also cannot have this behavior dynamic. Inheritance mapping is static because each new value in discriminator requires new mapped class.